# Not appear chart with Highcharts-ng

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, highcharts

I tried to use the plugin and angular.js Highcharts-ng for charting.

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/L78L4cuh/

But as you can see does not have any results.

I just do not understand the workings of it all. 
I used beyond the resources provided by the developer that produces the code, but I do not know how to use it

Here is the following code:

```
{"options":{"chart":{"type":"pie"},"plotOptions":{"series":{"stacking":""}}},"series":[{"data":[6,19,15,14,3,13,18,18,4,6],"id":"series-4","type":"area","color":"#0084CC","lineWidth":"","dashStyle":"Solid","name":"Twitter"},{"data":[16,16,16,13,11,3,6,2,6,19],"id":"series-5","name":"Sell","type":"area","color":"#B0E334","dashStyle":"Solid"}],"title":{"text":"Social Commerce Resul"},"credits":{"enabled":false},"loading":false,"size":{},"subtitle":{"text":"Awesome data about commerce"}}
```

How do I make it appear?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to add a few things to your code.
I updated your fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/L78L4cuh/1/

wrapped

```
<highchart id="chart1" config="highchartsNG"></highchart>
```

with proper angular calls
added jquery in dependencies
changed your js orders and added hightchart.js

Comment: I don't know Highcharts with angular, I only used it a while ago with jquery, maybe you can remove some dependencies on the fiddle if it still works